# IIS 8.5 Class not registered (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG) before Recycling apppool

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, c#-4.0

I have recently migrated an ASPX application from IIS 7 to IIS 8.5.

As a result, I sometimes get a "Class not registered" exception thrown. It will work completely fine after I recycle the Application Pool in IIS but after a while, it will stop working.

> Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
>   (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

and also this problem in the event viewer:

> Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other
>   applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The
>   applications or services that hold your registry file may not function
>   properly afterwards. No user action is required.
>
> DETAIL - 9 user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User\S-1-5-21-3577710392-836856763-939634836-4124:

Yesterday night I recreated the website and the application pool and this morning same problem occurred:

> Configuration (maybe too much details):
>
> - AppPool
>
>   - .Net CLR v4.0
>   - PipeLine Classic
>   - Enable 32-Bit Applications True
>   - Regular Time interval 0
>   - Recycling Every day at a specific time
> - WebSite
>
>   - Autentication Windows Authentication + Anonymous Authentication
>   - Kerberos
>   - Listen on 4 bindings (2 http and 2 https)
> - Application itself
>
>   - AnyCPU

Has anybody encountered this problem before, and how did you solve it?